# Как передать аргумент в функцию заранее?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, параметры, аргументы

Пусть есть некая функция, принимающая два аргумента:

```py
def foo(a, b):
    ...
    return something
```

Существует ли более правильный и питонистский способ добавить в эту функцию заранее, например, первый аргумент, кроме лямбды?

```py
foo = lambda b: foo(a=some_value, b)
```

Память подсказывает, что я что-то такое когда-то видел во время учёбы, связанное с редко используемыми возможностями *Python*, но так и не смог вспомнить что. Гугление на русском и английском и попытки полапатить документацию ничего не дали.

Этот вопрос не совсем абстрактный, например, `re.sub` принимает как аргумент функцию, которая должная принимать только один аргумент типа `re.Match`. В моей текущей задаче эта функция должна обращаться к внешнему словарю, а я не хочу портить код `global`ами и `nonlocal`ами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ещё использовать `functools.partial`, но только если хотите заменить последние именованные аргументы, с первыми так не получится из-за особенностей питона:

```py
from functools import partial

def foo(a, b):
    ...
    return something

foo2 = partial(foo, b = some_value)
foo2(123)
```

Ну, вернее, первые тоже можно заменить, но потом при вызове тогда явно придётся указывать названия оставшихся аргументов:

```py
foo2 = partial(foo, a = 2)
foo2(b=3)
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, это оно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
>>> some_value = 5
>>> 
>>> def foo(b, a=some_value):
    some_value = a + b
    return some_value

>>> foo(2)
7
>>>
```